# Long term consequenses of Mohammed's defeat

Tags: culture, politics, alternate-history

Supposing the army Mohammed led to sieze Mecca lost, and instead of being remembered as the founder of a widespread religion he was forgotten or overlooked by history. What would be the likely direction culture and politics (at least in the Middle East region, if not abroad) would take?

Comment: Too broad to tell. Something would have filled the gap, and political movements will find ideologies if they need one.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Byzantine and the Sassanid Empires would have survived. The muslims came right at the time both empires were at their weakest after a devastating war, but there wasn't really anyone else that would have been in a position to take advantage I think.

With the Byzantines retaining control of Anatolia, Syria, the Holy Land, and Egypt they would have been the dominant power in the entire Mediterranean area. With a perfectly legit claim to rule the entire area as well. Given their superior resources they should have been able to press that claim and gain control of Northern Africa, Italy, and Spain.

I believe the greater connection between Europe and the Eastern Mediterranean would have counteracted the loss of the Islamic World connecting Mediterranean to Persia and indirectly India and China. Sassanids were not hostile to trade, so links would have existed.

Similarly having Syria and Egypt remain strongly Christian would have counteracted the loss of the Islamic influence on Christian theology. Mohammed was not the only one wanting religious reform towards stronger monotheism. There probably would have been a Christian reformation starting in the east.

With Byzantines controlling or being able to control Italy, they would have been in position to force re-unification of the Church. And claim unification of the Roman Empire, as well. They would have also been in position to require that all Christian kings acknowledge their position as the Emperor and the protector of the faith.

Something resembling the Renaissance or the rich Islamic culture would have happened anyway. Starting from the Eastern Empire and then spreading to the west. It might have hit Europe earlier because of the better connection, but started slower than the flourishing of the Islamic culture due to lack of the Persian contribution. Unless, of course, the Empire succeeded in conquering Mesopotamia and actually keeping it. It was fairly close a few times, so it could happen.

In any case the resulting culture would be unique result of its unique circumstances. It would have the same roots as the Islamic and the Western and Eastern European cultures, so there would be lot that we would recognize, but it wouldn't be a new mix of current cultures it would be an entirely new culture that had evolved into new directions. Given its deep roots it would be a strong and rich culture, though.

Answer (score 0):

While Europe was in the throes of the dark ages there are some theories that Islam was quite technologically progressive. Specifically with mathematics and some sciences like astronomy...

Whether that can be attributed directly to the religion, or the culture, or some other series of circumstances, is unknown. it was likely a mixture of all of the above...

if history had taken a different turn you have to map out how trade with the east would have developed, if at all (do they have anything you want?) and if not, how the sharing of ideas might eventually lead to the renaissance. or not. And what it means to not have had a renaissance in Europe.

Answer (score -1):

It definitely would not be the same. There would be more pagans if he was overlooked by history, and Islam would not have that much power. That's probably why God gave him that power to permit him to accomplish his mission.
Middle East region would be mostly christian and dominated by Western Culture, would have no solid foundation and would politically be confused between Eastern Europe (Russia)'s and USA's influences.

Comment: Can you explain why these would be the case? For example, I don't quite follow why there would be more pagans. Other religions were around, no?

Comment: I think Mamadou123's referring to the polytheistic religions prominent in the Middle East at the time. Middle Eastern folklore, Zoroastrianism, Hinduism, Buddhism, even Taoism and Chinese folk religion, for instance, sometimes called "pagan" by those who follow Abrahamic religions, might have gained a foothold.